# pgp foreach merge same label but not the value

Tags: php, foreach

is it possible to merge same label of foreach but not the value?

here is what i have.

```
COUNTRY                 JAN 2017    FEB 2017
Japan                   US$4,670            
Philippines             US$4,589            
United States           US$2,001            
Philippines                         US$1,462        
Japan                               US$1,271        
Australia               US$1,096            
Mexico                  US$998          
United States                       US$725      
United Arab Emirates                US$655      
Australia                           US$471      
United Arab Emirates    US$337          
Singapore               US$316          
Switzerland             US$240          
Singapore                           US$201      
United Kingdom          US$158          
Germany                 US$140          
Netherlands             US$140          
Thailand                US$126          
New Zealand                         US$120      
Taiwan                  US$70           
Sweden                  US$70           
Austria                 US$65
```

here is what i want to display

```
COUNTRY                 JAN 2017    FEB 2017
Japan                   US$4,670    US$1,271        
Philippines             US$4,589    US$1,462        
United States           US$2,001    US$725                          
Australia               US$1,096    US$471      
Mexico                  US$998                                  
United Arab Emirates    US$337      US$655                                          
Singapore               US$316      US$201      
Switzerland             US$240                                  
United Kingdom          US$158          
Germany                 US$140          
Netherlands             US$140          
Thailand                US$126          
New Zealand                         US$120      
Taiwan                  US$70           
Sweden                  US$70           
Austria                 US$65
```

here is the output

```
Array
(
    [Japan_01-2017] => 4670
    [Philippines_01-2017] => 4589
    [United States_01-2017] => 2001
    [Philippines_02-2017] => 1462
    [Japan_02-2017] => 1271
    [Australia_01-2017] => 1096
    [Mexico_01-2017] => 998
    [United States_02-2017] => 725
    [United Arab Emirates_02-2017] => 655
    [Australia_02-2017] => 471
    [United Arab Emirates_01-2017] => 337
    [Singapore_01-2017] => 316
    [Switzerland_01-2017] => 240
    [Singapore_02-2017] => 201
    [United Kingdom_01-2017] => 158
    [Germany_01-2017] => 140
    [Netherlands_01-2017] => 140
    [Thailand_01-2017] => 126
    [New Zealand_02-2017] => 120
    [Taiwan_01-2017] => 70
    [Sweden_01-2017] => 70
    [Austria_01-2017] => 65
)
```

here is my code.

```
$countryarr[$i][$data['delivery_country']][$data['month'].'-'.$data['year']] = $usdval;

    $i++;
}

$sums = array();
foreach ($countryarr as $key => $values) {
    foreach ($values as $label => $count) {
        foreach ($count as $label2 => $count2) {
            $cmy = $label.'_'.$label2;
            /* echo $label.' '.$label2.' '.$count2.'<br/>'; */
            if (!array_key_exists($cmy, $sums)) {
                $sums[$cmy] = 0;
            }
            $sums[$cmy] += $count2;
        }
    }
}
arsort($sums);

foreach ($sums as $nlabel => $ncount) {
        $cex = explode('_',$nlabel);
        if($cex[1]==$last_monthn){
            $lastmonthsales = $currencies->format(($ncount/$currencies->get_value(strtoupper('USD'))), true, 'USD');
        }else{
            $lastmonthsales = "";
        }

        if($cex[1]==$this_monthn){
            $thismonthsales = $currencies->format(($ncount/$currencies->get_value(strtoupper('USD'))), true, 'USD');
        }else{
            $thismonthsales = "";
        }

?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $cex[0]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $lastmonthsales; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $thismonthsales  ?></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
<?php
        $a++;
    }
>
```

i tried to search about this problem. but i dont get an answer about this problem.

please help me how to achieve this problem.

thanks.

Comment: can you please post your array?

Comment: i update my code.. thanks.

Comment: does these value from database?

Comment: I mean the output array try var_dump($array)

Comment: please see update. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it:

```
$in = [
    'Japan_01-2017'                => 4670,
    'Philippines_01-2017'          => 4589,
    'United States_01-2017'        => 2001,
    'Philippines_02-2017'          => 1462,
    'Japan_02-2017'                => 1271,
    'Australia_01-2017'            => 1096,
    'Mexico_01-2017'               => 998,
    'United States_02-2017'        => 725,
    'United Arab Emirates_02-2017' => 655,
    'Australia_02-2017'            => 471,
    'United Arab Emirates_01-2017' => 337,
    'Singapore_01-2017'            => 316,
    'Switzerland_01-2017'          => 240,
    'Singapore_02-2017'            => 201,
    'United Kingdom_01-2017'       => 158,
    'Germany_01-2017'              => 140,
    'Netherlands_01-2017'          => 140,
    'Thailand_01-2017'             => 126,
    'New Zealand_02-2017'          => 120,
    'Taiwan_01-2017'               => 70,
    'Sweden_01-2017'               => 70,
    'Austria_01-2017'              => 65,
];

$out = [];
foreach ($in as $key => $value) {
    $parts = explode('_', $key);
    if (empty($out[$parts[0]])) {
        $out[$parts[0]] = [];
    }
    $out[$parts[0]][$parts[1]] = $value;
}

echo '<table><thead>
        <tr>
        <th>Country</th>
        <th>Jan 2017</th>
        <th>Frb 2017</th>
        </tr>
        </thead><tbody>';
foreach ($out as $country => $data) {
    $jan = isset($data['01-2017']) ? $data['01-2017'] : 0;
    $feb = isset($data['02-2017']) ? $data['02-2017'] : 0;
    echo "<tr>
            <td>$country</td>
            <td>$jan</td>
            <td>$feb</td>
           </tr>";
}
echo '</tbody></table>';
```

This will work but it is an awful way to do it, you really should be using some templating engine eg, twig to produce the html, so you would have the calculation separate from the view generation.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to have a map (array with country names as keys) and to hold a pair of values for each country. Something like

```
$model = array('Japan' => array(4670, 1271), ...);
```

Then you just loop through your current model and construct the new one:

```
foreach ($sums as $country => $value) {
    if (! $model[$country]) {
        $model[$country] = array(NULL, NULL);
    }
    $model[$country][$valueIsFromFirstMonth ? 0 : 1] = value;
}
```

Then you can loop through the new $model and print it.